# Retrieving integer values from an enum

Tags: c#, visual-studio, enums, enumeration

I have defined an enum and tried to retrieve it as follows

```
class Demo
{
    enum hello
    { 
        one=1,
        two
    }

    public static void Main()
    {           
        Console.WriteLine(hello.one);            

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Now, how do i retrieve the integer value "1" from the enum ?

Answer (score 3):

There's an explicit conversion from any enum type to its *underlying type* (`int` in this case). So:

```
Console.WriteLine((int) hello.one);
```

Likewise there's an explicit conversion the other way:

```
Console.WriteLine((hello) 1); // Prints "one"
```

(As a side note, I'd strongly advise you to follow .NET naming conventions, even when writing tiny test apps.)

Comment: Console.WriteLine((hello) 1); doesnt print "one". It prints "1" right ?

Comment: @DivakarRaj: No, it prints "one" because it's calling `ToString` on the *enum* value - it's like printing `hello.one`.

Answer (score 1):

you can cast the enums like

```
int a = (int)hello.one
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do a cast to int

```
Console.WriteLine((int)hello.one);
```

Comment: guess i was 4 sec too late :(

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
Console.Writeline((int)hello.Value);
```

or

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(hello.one);
```